# "Break On Exception" in Eclipse/Android

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm primarily a C#/VS dev, but will be debugging an Android application in the near future. I can't seem to find a setting in eclipse that will cause it to break into the debugger when an exception occurs (regardless of whether there is an exception handler handling it).

This feature is available in visual studio via the Debug > Exceptions menu.

Is there anything similar in eclipse? otherwise, how does one figure out the source of an exception assuming limited initial knowledge of the codebase?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't know whether this also applies to Android debugging, but the feature is available for Java. In Eclipse, switch to the "debug" perspective. In the "Breakpoint" view, you will notice a little icon (at the top right, near the "minimize" button of the view) with a J and an exclamation point. This is the trigger to add "exception" breakpoints.

With this dialog, you can tell the debugger to suspend and caught and uncaught exceptions alike.

Comment: You're welcome, that's one of my favorite debugging tools :p.

Comment: awesome, yep that totally did it. However, it breaks inside some API call, and just shows me an unhelpful screen asking me to point to the source file. Is there any way to tell it to only break in user-level code? so for example, MyMethod > SomeApiCall > SomeInternalCall > *exception is thrown* ... in this scenario I'd want it to break on SomeApiCall in MyMethod because I'm not interested in the internal call that generated the exception

Comment: Joel, you cannot (AFAIK) break on a specific exception with this : it will stop on all exceptions of that kind. As for stopping in "SomeApiCall" instead of "SomeInternalCall"; you cannot do it directly : set the exception breakpoint, wait for it to be thrown, select (in the "debug" view) the method you want to go back to, and use the "drop to frame" action to "go back" in the stack trace from "SomeInternalCall" to "SomeApiCall" or even further. That's difficult to describe ... http://www.certpal.com/blogs/2009/09/eclipse-tips-and-tricks-part-2 has a screenshot at "use the drop to frame action"

Comment: Make sure to go in and check "subclasses of this exception" in breakpoint properties, if that's relevant to you.  I had expected this to be the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

> how does one figure out the source of an exception assuming limited initial knowledge of the codebase

Inspectind stack trace you can find the line that causes exception. So you can wrap this come with try/catch and pus breakpoint to catch.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a project debuggable in the `AndroidManifest.xml` Second, the debugger should have a break point where you wan't to inspect the code. When starting the project in debugger in eclipse, the view will automatically jump to debugger as it hits a break point.

Hope this helps!