# android, application crashes when trying to open a certain activity

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, screen

I have a problem entering one activity/screen on an application I'm trying to develope. It seems that every time I press a button to open that activity, the application crashes. here is the java file:

```
public class login extends Activity{

// all kinds of functions //


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);


    place();

    btn_clr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clearForm();
        }
        });

    btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }
        });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and here is the layout.xml file:

```
< RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".login.java"
android:orientation="vertical" >

// setting all the buttons and texts //

< /RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the menu.xml file

```
< menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
< item

    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/log_str"/>

< /menu>
```

and this is the calling to the activity:

```
    btn_log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), login.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }
        });
```

It frustrate me for two days. Thank you in advance

Comment: and the logcat out put is?

Comment: Where is your `btn_clr` and `btn_back`, where have you initialized them..show your `place()` method

Comment: please post your manifest.xml also

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem was in the manifest.xml file. Now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The ideal thing to do in this case is to try to find the error through the debugger. One trick that you can use is to set a breakpoint on every exception ... that way, it will break as soon as the exception is thrown and you'll be able to inspect the error and the stack trace at the point of the error.

It was described in this answer (ironically, to a question I asked a while back :) ): https://stackoverflow.com/a/6342519/5416

> In Eclipse, switch to the "debug" perspective. In the "Breakpoint"
>   view, you will notice a little icon (at the top right, near the
>   "minimize" button of the view) with a J and an exclamation point. This
>   is the trigger to add "exception" breakpoints.
>
> With this dialog, you can tell the debugger to suspend and caught and
>   uncaught exceptions alike.